# Handling https request by jetty

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, ssl-certificate

I would like to write a SSL MITM proxy using Jetty. I've gone through some examples and it seems that I can use `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ConnectHandler` for HTTPS Connect tunneling.

Is there any way that I can set my own certificate and decrypt content using ConnectHandler?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, and I'm disappointed with the answer given by the developers at jetty, not sure if you solved it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204309/servlet-service-method-not-getting-called-for-connect-requests/16205822#16205822