# Is it possible to have Filters on a ConnectHandler?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I used the original jetty-proxy in Jetty 9, when the embedded start proxy server, after modifying the browser's proxy port, all access can be through the proxy server, I added my own filter in proxy server, add the way is:

```
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
FilterHolder fh = handler.addFilterWithMapping((Class<? extends Filter>) TLFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
context.addFilter(fh, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
```

But my filter can only filter HTTP requests, but I can't filter HTTPS .

Comment: I think this link will help you：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204309/servlet-service-method-not-getting-called-for-connect-requests/16205822#16205822

Comment: Filters can handle HTTP requests, regardless if they are plain text (`http://` or encrypted with TLS `https://`).  But `CONNECT` (as highlighted in your self answer below) has nothing to do with Filters or HTTP or web applications (where your Filters exist).  Now, ProxyServlet (a normal, non-CONNECT, proxy server) can have Filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development maintainers at jetty gave the results:
It is possible to deliver a CONNECT request to a Servlet service method, but it is ultimately futile to do so because it is impossible to handle a CONNECT inside a servlet. You don't really have access to the raw IO streams, only the HTTP content of the request/response. You can almost make his work, but never efficiently (no async IO etc.) So ultimately you will end up falling back to Jetty APIs anyway.

Also, why not just build on the support already provided by Jetty:

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ConnectHandler.html http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ProxyServlet.html

Comment: CONNECT is essentially a raw socket to a destination. Commonly encrypted.  Within a server that handles CONNECT you cannot decrypt the conversation between the client and the server.